# Pass array from controller to middleware Slim 3 PHP

Tags: php, rest, api, slim, middleware

I'm trying to pass an array with data to middleware and format it based on `Accept` HTTP header.
The controller gets the data from db and should pass it to the response object. Response object `write()` method accepts only strings:

```
public function getData(Request $request, Response $response): Response {
    return $response->write($this->getUsers());
    # This line of code should be fixed
}
```

The middleware should get the response and format it correctly:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $body = $response->getBody();

    switch ($request->getHeader('Accept')) {
        case 'application/json':
            return $response->withJson($body);
            break;
        case 'application/xml':
            # Building an XML with the data
            $newResponse = new \Slim\Http\Response(); 
            return $newResponse->write($xml)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/xml');
            break;
        case 'text/html':
            # Building a HTML list with the data
            $newResponse = new \Slim\Http\Response(); 
            return $newResponse->write($list)->withHeader('Content-type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
            break;
    }
}
```

I have a few routes behaves similarly:

```
$app->get('/api/users', 'UsersController:getUsers')->add($formatDataMiddleware);
$app->get('/api/products', 'UsersController:getProducts')->add($formatDataMiddleware);
```

By using middlewares I can add such functionality in a declarative way, keeping my controller thin.

How can I pass the original data array to response and implementing this pattern?

Comment: You might want to check https://github.com/akrabat/rka-content-type-renderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Response`-Object doesn't provide this functionallity nor has some extensions to do that. So you need to adjust the Response-Class

```
class MyResponse extends \Slim\Http\Response {
    private $data;
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }
    public function withData($data) {
        $clone = clone $this;
        $clone->data = $data;
        return $clone;
    }
}
```

Then you need to add the new Response to the Container

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['response'] = function($container) { // this stuff is the default from slim
    $headers = new Headers(['Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8']);
    $response = new MyResponse(200, $headers); // <-- adjust that to the new class

    return $response->withProtocolVersion($container->get('settings')['httpVersion']);
}
```

Now change the Response type to `MyResponse` and use the `withData` method

```
public function getData(Request $request, \MyResponse $response): Response {
    return $response->withData($this->getUsers());
}
```

At the end you can use the `getData` method and use its value and process it inside the middleware.

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, \MyResponse $response, callable $next) {
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $data = $response->getData();
    // [..]
}
```

That would be the answer to your question. A better solution in my opinion, would be a helper class which does what your middleware does, then you could something like this:

```
public function getData(Request $request, Response $response): Response {
    $data = $this->getUsers();        
    return $this->helper->formatOutput($request, $response, $data);
}
```

For that there is already a lib for: [rka-content-type-renderer](https://github.com/akrabat/rka-content-type-renderer)

Comment: I'll create a helper class :) Will check the lib as well. Thanks!